# Save two TextRanges together with some strings into one file, and then load this later, whats the best/easiest approach?

Tags: c#

I have two TextRanges from two different RichTextBoxes, and four strings from regular textboxes. I would like to save all this information in one file, and then be able to load it later. Whats the best approach?

I've been reading some about it, and it seems that reading all into one memorystream and then save it to a file is one way to do it. And then parse this content later.

Anyone that want to share some experience, and simple code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a simple approach consider creating a class with string properties for each of your textbox texts. You could then set the properties when you want to save your text, use XML serialization to save the class to an XML formatted file, and then read it back at a later time.

The advantage of this approach is that you will not need to hande low-level file handling or parsing yourself.

Searching for C# and XML Serialization will yield plenty of code examples.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is already provided by you: save in file and read after.

Another could be, in case if the data is too big, is using http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997372.aspx Memory Mapped Fies.